# When does the activated ability resolve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast a [Fiery Temper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFiery%20Temper%5d) targeting [Electrostatic Pummeler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElectrostatic%20Pummeler%5d). My opponent then pays 6 Enery Counters so that Pummeler can be a 4/4 but I responded with triggering [Dynavolt Tower](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDynavolt%20Tower%5d) dealing another 3 damage to Pummeler but he pays another 3 energy so that his Pummeler can be an 8/8. Is this correct? I think the way it works is that Pummeler will be 2/2 when my Dynavolt triggers and that will kill it. Or does Pummeler become an 8/8 and will only take 6 damage?

I think stack is like this

Fiery Temper -> Eloctrostatic Pummeler -> Pummeler Pays 6 Enery -> Dynavolt Tower -> Pummeler Pays 3 Energy

Comment: You mention "triggering Dynavolt Tower". Do you mean that at the beginning of this scenario, you have fewer than 5 energy counters, and that the energy you got from Dynavolt Tower's triggered ability allowed you to activate its activated ability?

Comment: Expand your explanation of what happened. Did the Fiery Temper and previous activations resolve, or were those objects still on the stack? How much energy did you have before triggering Dynavolt Tower? There is insufficient information in the question.

Comment: Clarification to my last: How much energy did you have before Casting Fiery Temper, thus triggering the first ability on Dynavolt Tower?

Answer (score 4):

There's a little ambiguity around the part where your opponent payed 6 energy to activate Electrostatic Pummeler's ability twice, but if we follow the tournament rules, the Pummeler survives this whole ordeal.

Assuming that you started out with enough energy to activate Dynavolt Tower, the situation plays out like this:

1. You cast Fiery Temper. This is the stack:

   - Fiery Temper
2. Your opponent declares that they pay 6 energy to activate Electrostatic Pummeler's ability twice. If we follow the tournament rules, then this is a shortcut for "Activate the ability, then let it resolve, then activate it again". This means that if you're responding to this, you have two choices. You can either respond to the first activation, or to the second.

   - If you respond to the first activation, you are interrupting the shortcut, so they have only activate the ability once. The Pummeler is a 1/1, your opponent still has 6+ energy, and this is the stack:

     - Pummeler's ability
     - Fiery Temper
   - Then the rest plays out like this:

     1. You pay 5 energy to activate Dynavolt Tower. This is the stack:

        - Dynavolt activated ability
        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     2. Your opponent activates Pummeler's ability twice with the 6 energy they still have. At this point, you have no responses, so both resolve, and the Pummeler ends up as a 4/4. This is still the stack:

        - Dynavolt activated ability
        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     3. Dynavolt Tower's ability resolves. The Pummeler is now a 4/4 with 3 damage marked. This is the stack:

        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     4. The Pummeler's ability resolves. The Pummeler is now an 8/8 with 3 damage marked. This is the stack:

        - Fiery Temper
     5. Fiery Temper resolves. The Pummeler is now an 8/8 with 6 damage marked. It survives.
   - If instead you respond to the second activation, you are accepting the shortcut, and one of the abilities has resolved. The Pummeler is a 2/2, your opponent has 3 energy, and this is the stack:

     - Pummeler's ability
     - Fiery Temper
   - Then the rest plays out like this:

     1. You pay 5 energy to activate Dynavolt Tower. This is the stack:

        - Dynavolt activated ability
        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     2. Your opponent activates Pummeler's ability once with the 3 energy they still have. At this point, you have no responses, so it resolves, and the Pummeler ends up as a 4/4. This is still the stack:

        - Dynavolt activated ability
        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     3. Dynavolt Tower's ability resolves. The Pummeler is now a 4/4 with 3 damage marked. This is the stack:

        - Pummeler's ability
        - Fiery Temper
     4. The Pummeler's ability resolves. The Pummeler is now an 8/8 with 3 damage marked. This is the stack:

        - Fiery Temper
     5. Fiery Temper resolves. The Pummeler is now an 8/8 with 6 damage marked. It survives.

---

If you started this situation with less than 5 energy, the situation is actually a lot simpler (assuming your opponent made correct plays). In this case, it plays out like this:

1. You cast Fiery Temper. This is the stack:

   - Dynavolt Tower's triggered ability
   - Fiery Temper
2. Your opponent responds declaring that they pay 6 energy to activate Electrostatic Pummeler's ability twice. This time, you don't have enough energy to activate Dynavolt Tower's activated ability, so both Pummeler activations resolve. The Pummeler is now a 4/4. This is still the stack:

   - Dynavolt Tower's triggered ability
   - Fiery Temper
3. Dynavolt Tower's triggered ability resolves. You gain 2 energy. This is the stack:

   - Fiery Temper
4. You activate Dynavolt Tower's activated ability. This is the stack:

   - Dynavolt Tower's activated ability
   - Fiery Temper
5. Your opponent activates Pummeler's ability again. You have no responses, so you let it resolve. Pummeler is now an 8/8. This is still the stack:

   - Dynavolt Tower's activated ability
   - Fiery Temper
6. Neither players have any more responses, so we let both the ability and the Fiery Temper resolve. Each deals 3 damage to the Pummeler, so the result is that the Pummeler is a 8/8 with 6 damage marked. Again, it survives.

Comment: There is the imperfect play possibility, if each player has sufficient energy, where the opponent activates the Pummeler the second time without letting the first resolve. If the Dynavolt Tower ability is then placed on the stack, above the two Pummeler activations, the third is insufficient to save the creature (3>2). While your Tournament Rules interpretation is accurate, it assumes facts that aren't in evidence.

Comment: I said that I was making the same interpretation assumptions in the tournament rules. Those rules are written with so that they generally match the intention of the players. It's reasonable in general to use their assumptions when interpreting MTG situations.

Comment: In general, nothing you've said is wrong. The room for disagreement is caused by the "Unclear What You're Asking" nature of the question, giving its loose use of MtG vernacular. Since the question is imprecisely asked, it is difficult to determine what the OP is wanting to know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pummeler starts as a 1/1, this is how it'd go down...

**STACK**

1. Electrostatic Pummeler is here
2. Fiery Temper targeting the pummeler
3. EP ability targeting self
4. EP ability targeting self
5. Dynavolt Tower targeting pummeler
6. Pummeler again targeting self

Now things start to resolve.

**STACK**

1. Electrostatic Pummeler is here
2. Fiery Temper
3. EP ability
4. EP ability
5. Dynavolt Tower
6. **RESOLVES** Pummeler is a 2/2

**STACK**

1. Electrostatic Pummeler is here.
2. Fiery Temper
3. EP ability
4. EP ability
5. **RESOLVES** Dynavolt Tower deals three damage, killing the pummeler.

Invalid targets essentially wipe the stack now.

If he was a more skilled player, he would have asked for a response to 3 before throwing 4 on the stack, boosting the pummeler to 2/2, which would become 4/4 when 5 resolves. It's 4/4(-3), resolves again to be 8/8(-3) then the Temper hits for more, but not enough to kill.